# My multiplication in python not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to get a multiplication inside a for loop working on the code below:

```
#products list and it's values per unity
tomato = 2
potato = 3
carrot = 1
pricePaid = int()

print("Welcome to my grocery shop!\n")

productList = ["Potato", "Tomato", "Carrot"]

print("What will you want today?\n""We have:")
print(*productList, sep=', ')
product = input("What will it be? ")

quantity = int(input("And how many do you want? "))

for productChoice in product:
    if productChoice == "Potato":
        pricePaid = quantity * potato
    elif productChoice == "Tomato":
        pricePaid = quantity * tomato
    elif productChoice == "Carrot":
        pricePaid = quantity * carrot

print("Here's your bag with {0} {1}s. The total is ${2:.2f}.".format(quantity, product, pricePaid))
```

but I'm getting a $0.00 as my results where it should be the quantity * productPrice:

```
"Here's your bag with 1 Tomatos. The total is $0.00."
```

Why is it failing? What am I missing here?

I'm using Python 3.x

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont think `for productChoice in product:` is doing what you think it is. Since `product` is a string (`input` returns strings), `productChoice` will be every letter in your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating through the characters in the input, and setting the price paid each time. There's no need to iterate, as `product` doesn't change. Removing that `for` loop does the trick. You also need to remove the references to `productChoice`, since it (literally) has no purpose.

```
#products list and it's values per unity
tomato = 2
potato = 3
carrot = 1
pricePaid = int()

print("Welcome to my grocery shop!\n")

productList = ["Potato", "Tomato", "Carrot"]

print("What will you want today?\n""We have:")
print(*productList, sep=', ')
product = input("What will it be? ")

quantity = int(input("And how many do you want? "))

if product == "Potato":
    pricePaid = quantity * potato
elif product == "Tomato":
    pricePaid = quantity * tomato
elif product == "Carrot":
    pricePaid = quantity * carrot

print("Here's your bag with {0} {1}s. The total is ${2:.2f}.".format(quantity, product, pricePaid))
```

Comment: Thanks, @jhpratt. That's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is causing your issues:

```
for productChoice in product:
    if productChoice == "Potato":
        pricePaid = quantity * potato
    elif productChoice == "Tomato":
        pricePaid = quantity * tomato
    elif productChoice == "Carrot":
        pricePaid = quantity * carrot
```

If we changed that to this quickly we can see why

```
for productChoice in product:
    print(productChoice)
```

The output to that with product being "Tomato"

```
T
o
m
a
t
o
```

What you are doing here is iterating over each character in the string `product`, when you don't actually want this behavior. The fix to your problem is just removing the for loop, keeping the selection only.

This is all you need:

```
if product == "Potato":
    pricePaid = quantity * potato
elif product == "Tomato":
    pricePaid = quantity * tomato
elif product == "Carrot":
    pricePaid = quantity * carrot
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the **letters** in `producChoice`.

Add a `print(productChoice)` to your loop in order to watch what happens.
Since no single letter equals one of your products, none of the conditional statements will be triggered and `pricePaid` will stay at its original value of `int() == 0`.

There's no need for the `for` loop here at all, so just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Here an improved code using dictionaries. Dictionaries alone are worth studying to make code much lighter. Basically a dictionary is composed by keys (for instance tomato) holding values (for instance 1). You can get those values by using .get().

```
#products list and it's values per unity
prices = dict(tomato=2,potato=3,carrot=1)

product = input('''\
Welcome to my grocery shop!
What will you want today?
We have: {}
What will it be?
'''.format(', '.join(prices.keys()))).lower()

quantity = int(input("And how many do you want? "))

pricePaid = prices.get(product,0) * quantity

if pricePaid:
    print("Here's your bag with {0} {1}s. The total is ${2:.2f}."
          .format(quantity, product, pricePaid))
else:
    print("Error with input!")
```

---

Comment: As much as this may work, it completely changes the code at hand, and doesn't give the poster any help with *why* the code they have fails.

Comment: But who's to say that they even understand what the code does with your rewrite?

Comment: Thanks, @AntonvBR. That is helpful to see how my code could have been rewritten. I do understand, but it will take a while for me to absorb this concept. I really appreciate your answer!.

Comment: @RGregg I understand and it looks like you already are familiar with unpacking, string formatting. Dictionaries are simple to learn! Try it!

Comment: @RGregg one difference between this and the `if` statements is that this code will fail if you enter a product that isn't supported. That may be a feature or a bug, depending on your point of view.

Comment: @RGregg Yep this doesn't handle errors in input, yet.